# Android BMI calculator using LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, observer-pattern

I have made a [Body mass index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index)-calculator using ViewModel and LiveData.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Source-code of the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.bmirechner

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.bmirechner.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: BmiViewModel

    fun updateUi() {
        val bmi = viewModel.computeBmi()
        binding.resultTextView.text = bmi.toString()

        var messageText = ""
        when {
            bmi < 20 -> messageText = resources.getString(R.string.text_underweight)
            bmi in 20.0..25.0 -> messageText = resources.getString(R.string.text_normal_weight)
            bmi > 25 && bmi <= 30 -> messageText = resources.getString(R.string.text_overweight)
            bmi > 30 -> messageText = resources.getString(R.string.text_heavy_overweight)
            else -> messageText = resources.getString(R.string.error)
        }

        binding.messageTextView.text = messageText
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BmiViewModel::class.java)

        binding.currentWeightTextView.text = viewModel.getCurrentWeight().value.toString()
        binding.currentHeightTextView.text = viewModel.getCurrentHeight().value.toString()

        binding.heightSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                viewModel.setCurrentHeight(progress.toDouble())
                viewModel.getCurrentHeight().observe(this@MainActivity, Observer {
                    binding.currentHeightTextView.text = it.toString()
                })
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                updateUi()
            }
        })

        binding.weightSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                viewModel.setCurrentWeight(progress.toDouble())
                viewModel.getCurrentWeight().observe(this@MainActivity, Observer {
                    binding.currentWeightTextView.text = it.toString()
                })
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                updateUi()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Source-Code of the ViewModel:

```
package com.example.bmirechner

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import kotlin.math.pow
import kotlin.math.round

class BmiViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var currentHeight = MutableLiveData<Double>()
    private var currentWeight = MutableLiveData<Double>()

    init {
        currentHeight.value = 0.0
        currentWeight.value = 0.0
    }

    fun setCurrentHeight(value: Double) {
        currentHeight.value = value
    }

    fun setCurrentWeight(value: Double) {
        currentWeight.value = value
    }

    fun getCurrentHeight(): MutableLiveData<Double> {
        return currentHeight
    }

    fun getCurrentWeight(): MutableLiveData<Double> {
        return currentWeight
    }

    fun computeBmi(): Double {
        val factor = 10
        val heightInMeter = currentHeight.value!! / 100.0
        val bmi = currentWeight.value!! / heightInMeter.pow(2)
        return round(bmi * factor) / factor
    }
}
```

**Is my LiveData-usage correct or should it be modified?**

**What parts of my implementation could be improved?**

Looking forward to reading your comments and answers.

Comment: Perhaps add instruction related to units used for height/weight :) (cm/kg)

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks. I really should have done so.

Comment: i would appreciate if you had put the actions from your slider into a method and could avoid the redundant code. (that far to little for a whole review - its just a side note ^^)